# HP ProLiant ML350 G6: Does the RAID rebuild automatically?

Tags: raid, hp, hp-proliant, hardware-raid, hp-smart-array

A SAS HDD in our ML350 is faulty.

We're buying a new one and I wanted to ask if I can just take out the faulty one and insert the new one with the server on to let it rebuild the raid or any manual operation is required.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The RAID rebuild on HP servers is automatic if you're using a Smart Array RAID controller. Assuming a Smart Array P410 array controller, all you'll need to do is insert the replacement hard disk to initiate the rebuild.

The details of how the Smart Array handles drive failures and rebuilds are described here in the [HP Smart Array controller technology brief](https://www.hpe.com/h20195/v2/getpdf.aspx/4AA5-4124ENW.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

If you RAID is hot swap it will rebuild. Before pulling the drive check in the HP management agent and check it says that "HOT Swap" is enabled. Also what is the RAID Version? As pulling a drive that isn’t in a HOT Swap RAID will cause you more issues than it’s worth.